# Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) '$npm_package_options_mocha'

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js

I encounter the following error when trying to start the development server using `yarn run`. It seems something to do with path to npm package options mocha. I'm using Windows 8.1. I installed cross-env if it involved NODE env variable, but to no avail. Can you describe why this is happening?

```
Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) '$npm_package_options_mocha'
    at Object.lookupFiles (C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\addis_map\google-maps-react
ode_modules\mocha\lib\utils.js:634:15)
    at C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\addis_map\google-maps-react\node_modules\mocha\
n\_mocha:327:30
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\addis_map\google-maps-react
ode_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:326:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
Done in 46.84s.
```